# javascript: how to call function on appbar by id in windows store apps?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

i am currently developing an windows store app on the platform of JavaScript, I have added a button in the app bar.

If the button is clicked, it should be open `fb.me/mypage`. I dunno how to do this ? help me out.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="appBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="">
        <button 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{id:'button1',label:'Like Us',icon:'like',
                section:'selection',tooltip:'Like us'}">
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () { //Whatever you want to do                    
            });

Comment: @Manvik But i don't know where to place your code in `default.js`

Comment: args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () { //place it here});

Comment: @Manvik can u pls make your comment as an answer, i will mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () { //Whatever  you want to do });
```

Place the above code in

```
    args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () { //place it here});
```

Comment: what is link for `Rate and Review` page ?

Comment: What do you want to rate and review...there is no such page I know